# Impossible speedups when using JIT in python. What's going on?

Tags: python, jit

I'm trying to test the speed improvement of using JIT in python. Here's the code I'm using.

```py
from numba import jit
import timeit

@jit # Commented out when testing pure python
def sumof():
    x = 0
    for i in xrange(1000000000):
        x += 1
    return x

def timer():
    sumof() # Run once to initialize the JIT compiler
    l = []
    t = timeit.default_timer()
    for x in range(10):
        l.append(sumof())
    return timeit.default_timer()-t, l # Returns the time elapsed and the list of results, to verify accuracy

print timer()
```

This gives a result similar to this

```
(5.643910299113486e-06, [1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000])
```

Now I know raw CPU performance is orders of magnitude faster than pure python, but 10 billion operations in 5 microseconds?? I tested this same code, but using the maximum value of a signed 64 bit integer instead of just a billion. This was the result.

```
(5.643909389618784e-06, [9223372036854775807L, 9223372036854775807L, 9223372036854775807L, 9223372036854775807L, 9223372036854775807L, 9223372036854775807L, 9223372036854775807L, 9223372036854775807L, 9223372036854775807L, 9223372036854775807L])
```

~ 92 quadrillion operations... in 5 microseconds. By my math, that's about 16 septillion operations a second. Something is obviously wrong, yet it's giving the correct result. I suspect the compiler is getting rid of the for loop somehow, but why? And how can I prevent it?

Comment: `for i in xrange(1000000000): x += 1` is a very simple loop (simplifies to `1000000000` of course), perhaps the machine code is optimising it out altogether.

Comment: Umm, isn't this the result of your benchmark? At least in this case, the speedup factor when using numba's jit really is 10^8.

Comment: @101 It also happens when I replace the function with a general "multiplication by repeated addition" function. Where the loop is replaced with `for i in xrange(a): x+= b`. I agree with you that it's a simple loop, and I can see how the compiler throws the one in my question away, but are compilers really that magical to do that too?

Comment: @phihag It's not possible to optimize a program to the point that it's operating at half a billion times the clock rate of the computer. It's just simply impossible.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're interested in clockrate. You seem to be assuming that every Python assignment corresponds to at least one CPU cycle, which is not necessarily true - for instance, [dead code elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination) can take place, or, in this case, [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding). Does the program return the correct result? If yes, then the optimization is valid.

Comment: @phihag I do see what you mean, but I was trying to test the speed of the loop, not the speed of the code once the loop is cut out through optimization.

Comment: But the whole point of a an optimizer - especially JIT - is that you can optimize away superfluous CPU cycles like this! To test the speed of the loop without optimization, remove the `@jit`. Alternatively, make the program more complex - say, calculate Pi, or solve an instance of the travelling salesman problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty likely that the optimizer has replaced the loop with a single constant calculation.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization for a list of classic loop optimizations.  In this case, completely unrolling the loop, then combining all the constants, results in `return n` (with x += 1) or `return n * b` (with x += b).  Using `x += i` results in `return n * (n + 1) / 2`.  (In each case `n` is the appropriate upper loop bound: when summing `i` in `range(n)`, it's really just `n-1` instead.)

Because this is a JIT compiler, it can do this even for variable `n`, although in your examples each `n` is a constant, so even non-JIT compilers can do this.

Comment: Well damn, compilers are just smarter than I thought.